# PhpStorm Vuejs file move adds '/types' to 'vuex' import statement

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm, vuex

I'm working with Vue.js single file components in PhpStorm.  When I move a component file into another directory, PhpStorm is adding `/type` to the end of any vuex import statement, (which blows them up until I do a find/replace to set them all back).

For example:

```
import {mapActions} from 'vuex';
```

gets changed to:

```
import {mapActions} from 'vuex/types';
```

Anyone know what is causing this or how to fix it?  Seems like an odd glitch or maybe setting in the refactoring abilities of PhpStorm ???

Comment: what IDE version do you work with? It's not an issue for me in 2019.1.3 and 2019.2 EAP

Comment: lol, guess it was fixed in 2019.1.3, just upgraded from 2019.1.2 and problem solved, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to have been a bug in version 2019.1.2, upgrading to 2019.1.3 fixed it.